# MySQL Dynamic inner join for combining multiple rows into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a database with the tables below, where shop_id in *hours* refers to a an id in shop.
Preferably I would have a query to return all data in one row, in stead of needing to post-process a lot of rows to "merge" the result from hours so the end result looks like this.

```
+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| name              | address | zip  | city    | municipal      | phone    | lat           | lng           | day | day | day | day | day | day | day |
+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Coop Marked Budal | false   | 7298 | Budalen | Midtre gauldal | 72436410 | 62.8837013245 | 10.4836997986 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |
+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Right now I have come to the query below, wich I feel there must be a better alternative to. So my question is: **Is there really another solution to this?**
Also, I've seen concat, but I want to avoid having to split strings later on when processing the data.

```
select shop.name, shop.address, shop.zip, shop.city, shop.municipal, shop.phone, shop.lat, shop.lng,
h.day, hh.day, hhh.day, hhhh.day, hhhhh.day, hhhhhh.day, hhhhhhh.day
from shop
/**
As it requires a unique table name, this was the solution I found.
Could this be shortened?
**/
inner join hours h on shop.id = h.shop_id and h.day = 1
inner join hours hh on shop.id = hh.shop_id and hh.day = 2
inner join hours hhh on shop.id = hhh.shop_id and hhh.day = 3
inner join hours hhhh on shop.id = hhhh.shop_id and hhhh.day = 4
inner join hours hhhhh on shop.id = hhhhh.shop_id and hhhhh.day = 5
inner join hours hhhhhh on shop.id = hhhhhh.shop_id and hhhhhh.day = 6
inner join hours hhhhhhh on shop.id = hhhhhhh.shop_id and hhhhhhh.day = 7;
```

---

**Tables**

```
shop
+----+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| id | name              | address | zip  | city    | municipal      | phone    | lat           | lng           | chain_id | county_id |
+----+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Test              | false   | 1234 | Test    | Test           | 12341234| 0.0000         | 0.0000        |        3 |        16 |
+----+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------+----------+---------------+---------------+----------+-----------+


hours
+-----+----------+----------+---------+
| day | open     | close    | shop_id |
+-----+----------+----------+---------+
|   1 | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 |       1 |
|   2 | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 |       1 |
|   3 | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 |       1 |
|   4 | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 |       1 |
|   5 | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 |       1 |
|   6 | 09:00:00 | 20:00:00 |       1 |
|   7 | 14:00:00 | 20:00:00 |       1 |
+-----+----------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a case .. when to do the pivot, and then group by the shop fields and use an aggregate function to process the day.

```
select 
    shop.NAME, shop.address, shop.zip, shop.city, shop.municipal, shop.phone, shop.lat, shop.lng,
    MAX(CASE WHEN h.DAY = 1 THEN h.DAY ELSE 0 END) AS Day1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN h.DAY = 2 THEN h.DAY ELSE 0 END) AS Day2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN h.DAY = 3 THEN h.DAY ELSE 0 END) AS Day3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN h.DAY = 4 THEN h.DAY ELSE 0 END) AS Day4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN h.DAY = 5 THEN h.DAY ELSE 0 END) AS Day5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN h.DAY = 6 THEN h.DAY ELSE 0 END) AS Day6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN h.DAY = 7 THEN h.DAY ELSE 0 END) AS Day7
from shop
    INNER JOIN HOURS h ON shop.id = h.shop_id
group by
    shop.NAME, shop.address, shop.zip, shop.city, shop.municipal, shop.phone, shop.lat, shop.lng;
```

Just a note about what you want displayed in the day columns:
AFAIK if any of the hours rows for a shop : day is missing, your current query will drop the whole row? If you want this behaviour repeated, you will need to also add in a where clause.